# What exactly is a maximal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am confused about the definition of maximal ideal. Suppose that there is ring $R$. Now if we select the whole $R$ to be an ideal, then wouldn't this be maximal ideal? Or is the definition of maximal ideal stating that whole $R$ cannot be maximal ideal?

Secondly, can anyone show why in the ring of integers $p\mathbb{Z}$ is maximal ideal whenever $p$ is prime?

Comment: As can be seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_ideal) $I\ne R$ is explicitly required.

Answer (score 3):

The definition requires $I$ to be a *proper* ideal. Why? Because if it didn't, "maximal ideal" would be a really boring concept.

Here are two ways to show $p\mathbb{Z}$ is maximal in $\mathbb{Z}$. First is direct. Say there exists something larger, $p\mathbb{Z} \subset I$. Pick $a \in I \setminus p\mathbb{Z}$. Because $p$ is prime, and $a$ is not a multiple of $p$, they are coprime. By Bezout's lemma, we have some $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ax + py = 1$; this implies $1 \in I$. That forces $I = \mathbb{Z}$.

The other requires a bit more machinery, but it gives a good reason for why we should care about maximal ideals. It turns out that $I$ is a maximal ideal in $R$ iff $R/I$ is a field. Since $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field, $p\mathbb{Z}$ is maximal in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

An ideal $I$ is called *maximal* if it is [proper](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperIdeal.html) and there are no other ideals *other than the ring itself* that properly contain $I$.  In other words, you cannot have another ideal $J$ such that $I \subsetneq J \subsetneq R$.  Another way to say this is that if we have $I \subseteq J$, then $I = J$ or $J = R$.  To emphasize: any maximal ideal $I$ must be *properly contained* in $R$.

Approaching directly from the definitions, recall that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a [principal ideal domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain); so if $p\mathbb{Z}$ is not maximal, then $p\mathbb{Z} \subset m\mathbb{Z}$ for some integer $m \neq \pm 1$.  Is this possible?

---

Alternatively, we can use this important theorem:

> $I \subset R$ is a maximal ideal *if and only if* the quotient ring $R/I$ is a field.

Because $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field, this allows us to conclude that $p\mathbb{Z}$ is maximal in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

We call an ideal M of a ring R to be a maximal ideal, if we cannot squeeze any other ideal between M and R. Suppose if we could do so, then either that ideal becomes M or R.
Mathematically, M is a maximal ideal of R if $M\subset K \subset R$, then either $M=K $ $or $ $K=R$.
Next consider $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, the ring of integers modulo p, where p is a prime. We have a result, which says that $M$ $is$ $a$ $maximal$ $ideal$ $of$ $R$ $\iff$ $R/M$ $is$ $a$ $field$. Since $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is  afield, so $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ whenever p is prime.